# Getting error: /bin/sh scriptcs: command not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, scriptcs, vscode-code-runner

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Mac, running extension CodeRunner. 
I've got a simple program:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorldApplication {
class HelloWorld {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("hellowol");
   }
 }
}
```

When I run it using the play button in the upper right hand corner I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh scriptcs: command not found
```

Then

```
[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.008 seconds
```

The program does not show the desired output.

**EDIT: Much thanks to @VonC. His approach worked.**
Pro tip for anyone: install scriptcs using

```
brew install scriptcs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering [the prerequisite](https://github.com/filipw/vscode-scriptcs-runner#pre-requisities) for [`filipw/vscode-scriptcs-runner`](https://github.com/filipw/vscode-scriptcs-runner) is:

> [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) should be installed on your machine.

Make sure to launch VSCode from a shell session where scriptcs is in your `$PATH` (meaning `which scriptcs` does not return an empty output)

Comment: thanks so much for helping. This fixed it but now I have a new error: Unexpected named argument: Users/jfitz/Projects/Projtest/test.cs

Comment: @jamesfdearborn That would be better asked as a separate question.

Comment: Will do in 90 minutes, when I can post questions.

Comment: @Vonc Hi VonC I am sorry to disturb you, I find similar issue, I run "which scriptcs" it gives me /usr/local/bin/scriptcs. And I start Visual code from a shell session by running following command: "/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron", but when I run the code it still displays this error. Could you advise? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HuibinZhang Electron? VSCode should be launched by typing `code`. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac. See if the issue persists when VSCode is launched that way.

Comment: @Vonc thanks for kind reply. I will try this and let you know:)

Comment: @HuibinZhang Since it is still failing, try and display PATH within vscode (using a console)

Comment: @Vonc hi I tried display PATH it looks like this:
C02RW5PQG8WN:~ i333417$ which scriptcs
/usr/local/bin/scriptcs
C02RW5PQG8WN:~ i333417$ scriptcs "/var/folders/sr/5jzw91rn4g3cc2b0xyhw0j100000gq/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.csharp"
Unexpected named argument: var/folders/sr/5jzw91rn4g3cc2b0xyhw0j100000gq/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.csharp
C02RW5PQG8WN:~ i333417$

Comment: @Vonc Hi it still display command not found. I mean I tried copy "/var/folders/sr/5jzw91rn4g3cc2b0xyhw0j100000gq/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.csharp" statement and paste to terminal to run, it gives me "Unexpected named argument:" error, but on the output window it still say /bin/sh: scriptcs: command not found

Comment: @Vonc, I don't know why it gives me the scriptcs command not found error as I type scriptcs in the terminal, it doesn't give me that error.

Comment: @Vonc, it is weird, now after I click run it gives me "Unexpected named argument: var/folders/sr/5jzw91rn4g3cc2b0xyhw0j100000gq/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.csharp". Could you let me know how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: @HuibinZhang Then it would be better to explain that issue in a separate question (with a link back to this one)

Comment: @VonC I have post a separated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990818/got-unexpected-named-argument-error-when-running-csharp-code-on-visual-studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try "brew install scriptcs" in your terminal.